# jQuery slider, Autoplay SWF when slided to

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, slider

I've serach google for a while to get an answer to this question.

I want to build a slider with JavaScript that both have images and my own SWF movies.
The problem is that i want this slider to slide automatic and when it hits a SWF movie i should play that automatic and when the movie ends continue with the slide.
And ofcourse i want it to loop.

I need a finger in the right direction where to find examples and help.

Regards
Erik

Comment: Just want to add, i dont want to embed youtube clips or anything like that. My own created SWF animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using SWFObject plugin (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), and JW Player (http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/). If it's just a movie, FLV might be a better format.

On the event that your page should load, you need to do a $.ajax request to get the flashvars for the appropriate file. In your flashvars, you need to create the div to have your video player appended to, and make sure 'autostart' is set to true.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/flashvars.js',
        dataType: 'script',
        cache: false
    });
```

To set it up with a slider, try integrating it with jCarousel. That should do it.

Comment: I tired this, http://pastebin.com/GdZ4RkjK. Running jQuery Cycle. Marked up so a class is added to the div round the flash element. So that way i can detect if that div is visible, and if thats true it should pause the cycle and then resume after a given time. But the code dosent work that well. Dont fully understand the "setInterval" and "clearInterval"

Comment: can you send me some of the swf files you're using and/or the html markup? a live example would also be good.

Comment: Here is the exampel, here can you se the html markup. http://brandsonstrategi.se/cedervall/wp/